# Meteor user gets logged out when I update the user document in the database

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Edit: Just discovered that this error doesn't depend on the code that I pasted here, so I'll just remove it. Basically, if I update the user document in any way, wherever the user is on my page he gets logged out. Why is this and how have I not run into this before if it *should* be that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Meteor connection from client to database is constant. When you update the user , you're actually updating the entire document. This will cause a conflict in state.

In general it's actually bad practice to store info inside the user collection. You should move any data to a separate profile collection(s)

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered my code examples don't matter, because it's true for anything I update and wherever I sit on my page.

Comment: But how can I not have run into this problem before, if what you say is true? I know for a FACT that I have updated user documents before without running into this problem. But I'll do as you say and create a different collection for this data.

Comment: I do not deny it can be finicky, especially when it comes to publish/subscribe. However part of the problem lies in when updating the profile, you're replacing the entire existing profile object with your data object, so anything that was there before, including the name key, is going to be wiped out.